# Cant write files do server with Filestream class (Return 400 - Bad Request)

Tags: asp.net, .net, api, iis, filestream

When i try to write a image file to server, using this little code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] ImgViewModel imagem)
    {

        try
        {
            if (imagem.base64.Contains(","))
            {
                imagem.base64 = imagem.base64
                  .Substring(imagem.base64
                  .IndexOf(",") + 1);
            }

            imagem.FileAsByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(imagem.base64);

            var folderName = Path.Combine("Resources", "Images");
            var pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);

            var ext = Path.GetExtension(imagem.filename);
            var fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ext;
            var dbPath = Path.Combine(folderName, fileName);

            using (var fs = new FileStream(dbPath, FileMode.CreateNew))
            {
                fs.Write(imagem.FileAsByteArray, 0,
                         imagem.FileAsByteArray.Length);
                fs.Close();

            }

            ImageViewModel img = new ImageViewModel()
            {
                ExternalId = new Guid(imagem.id),
                Type = (ImageType)1,
                Url = dbPath

            };

            var imgx = Mapper.Map<ImageViewModel, Domain.Entities.Image>(img);

            _service.Add(imgx);
            _service.Commit();


            return new OkObjectResult(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(imagem));

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

    }
```

I got a 400 - Bad Request error. I just commented this part of the code:

```
 using (var fs = new FileStream(dbPath, FileMode.CreateNew))
             {
                fs.Write(imagem.FileAsByteArray, 0,
                         imagem.FileAsByteArray.Length);
                fs.Close();

        }
```

and published it again, without Filestream file writing, and the rest of code worked fine.
So, the error is in this part of the code.

Also, i've put this code on top of my class, trying to get server's permission  to write these image files

`[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]`

Also, in the server, i think that i've set correctly those permissions needed to write files

Anybody knows what i'm missing??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you want a full path there...  try using AppContext.BaseDirectory for the first part.... or use the variable you already defined as "pathToSave"

Comment: Could you please tell me the details 400 bad request error message and the substaus codes for your error codes? Normally, the 400 means there is something wrong with your request.

Comment: I just figured whats going on..
File Stream could not create /RESOURCES/IMAGES folder.
But it doenst return a 400 error with message. Just throws 400 error and nothing more